# Предупреждение: Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Tags: python, pandas

Делаю масштабирование признаков, записанных в pandas.DataFrame, но анаконда выдает **2 одинаковых предупреждения**:

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
for i in (df.columns[:]):
    scaler.fit(df_train[i].values.reshape(-1,1))
    df_train[i + 'sc'] = scaler.transform(df_train[i].values.reshape(-1,1))
    df_test[i + 'sc'] = scaler.transform(df_test[i].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Заменял все

```
df_train[i + 'sc'] = ...
df_test[i + 'sc'] = ...
```

на

```
df_train.loc[:,i] = ...
df_t.loc[:,i] = ...
```

Вот так:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
for i in (df.columns[:]):
    scaler.fit(df_train[i].values.reshape(-1,1))
    df_train.loc[:, i + 'sc'] = scaler.transform(df_train.loc[:,i].values.reshape(-1,1))
    df_test.loc[:, i + 'sc'] = scaler.transform(df_test.loc[:, i].values.reshape(-1,1))
```

Вместо двух предупреждений **осталось одно**.

И тот, и другой код рабочий, но хотелось бы разобраться:

1. как успокоить анаконду
2. можно ли реализовать без цикла (с использованием матричных операций)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду вы хотите сохранить нормализованные данные в качестве новых столбцов с суффиксом `sc`. Если вы хотите сохранить оригинальные данные, толучше будет сохранить нормализованный дата сет в качестве отдельного DataFrame'а. Нормализацию обычно делают до разделения данных на обучающую и тестовую выборки.

> "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." [(c) Linus Torvalds](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Linus_Torvalds#2000-04)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# reading data
#df = pd.read_csv(...)

target_cols = ['<target column name>']

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df.loc[:, df.columns.drop(target_cols), 
                 index=df.index, columns=df.columns.drop(target_cols))
# NOTE: we don't want to normalize / scale a target column
Y = df.loc[:, target_cols]

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25)
```

Comment: Возможно, моя логика не верна, но я нормализовал, зафитив scaler на train выборке, потому что показалось, что test  - это данные, которые стали известны после построения модели, и мы не могли знать, какие в них будут значения. Соответственно и среднее со стандартным отклонением будет другим со знанием данных в test выборке.

Comment: @IaroslavIV, это зависит от того как рассматривать входные данные... Например у вас есть заведомо размеченный набор данных. Его можно разделить на две части - обучающая и тестовая выборки либо на три - обучающая, проверочная и валидационная. В последнем случае предсказывающая модель не должна видеть валидационную выборку на этапе обучения и проверки. Но по-моему, суть вашего вопроса в другом...